# Update pandas value when regex condition is satisfied with regex replace

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

Giving a DataFrame like this one, composed by more than 10k records:

```
    RecSeq Length   Recognition Sequence    Enzymes
4023    12  CCANNNNNNTGG    BstXI
4024    12  CGANNNNNNTCC    HdeNY26I
4025    12  CGANNNNNNTGC    BcgI
4026    12  GAACNNNNNCTC    PpiI
4027    12  GAAGNNNNNCTC    Mcr10I
4028    12  GACNNNNNNGTC    AasI
4029    12  GACNNNNNNGTC    DrdI
4030    12  GACNNNNNNGTC    DseDI
```

I want to replace any N under the column `Recognition Sequence` using a regex expression, which will replace `N` with `[A|C|G|T]`. Currently I'm doing that with `iterrows` by adding every records inside a novel dataframe (`else` condition preserves the row as it is, so I did not include its code inside). Here's how:

```
new_df = []
    for idx, i in df.iterrows():
        if re.search('N', i[1]) != None:
            value = str(i[1])
            updated = value.replace('N', '[A|C|G|T]')
            whole_line = str(updated +','+ i[2],+','+i[0])
            new_df.append(whole_line)
            df1  = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
```

This approach appears slow because it iterates over every element, and I know that iterating is always the last way to follow while handling with pandas. I want to implement a `np.where` as explained into other question or something more versatile or powerful.

Yes, every `N` should be replaced with `[A|C|G|T]`. This is what I was doing with my code.

Comment: so you want to add `[A|C|G|T]` 10 times if 10 `N` are present in the string? For example `CGNNNT` will change into `CG[A|C|G|T][A|C|G|T][A|C|G|T]T`. Also what is `N` does not appear together, like `CGNTN`, then what output you want?

Comment: Can you post your expected output as well, so we don;t have to guess what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['CCANNNNNNTGG']})

df
        A
0   CCANNNNNNTGG

import re
def my_func(x):
    return re.sub(r'N', [A|C|G|T], x)

df['A'] = df.A.apply(my_func)

df
0    CCA[A|C|G|T][A|C|G|T][A|C|G|T][A|C|G|T][A|C|G|T][A|C|G|T]TGG
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: This code does the substitution just one time for every `N`

Comment: @Shred you just need to change the regex. You can anytime edit the regex as per your requirement. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Damn I was doing it in a really stupid way. In my case I found more suitable the use of `str.replace`, but your approach using `df.apply` becomes useful and clean with multiple regex conditions.